# How to remove rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb in ubuntu 16.04 linux machine

Tags: uninstall, amazon-ec2, rstudio

```
$ sudo apt-get remove  rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb'
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove purge rstudio-server`

Comment: `dpkg -r rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb`

Comment: @Raphael It will be `sudo apt-get remove rstudio-server` . Both purge and remove shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 15):

Guess here that you installed `rstudio-server` by downloading it from an external source and then installing it using `dpkg` or `GDebi`. So, you are trying to remove it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

But, `rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb` is the name of the file. The software is installed as: `rstudio-server`. So, the correct command will be:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge rstudio-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit the question [How can I reproduce the error "package... needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it" for testing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967944/how-can-i-reproduce-the-error-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-f) and go to the **How to manage broken packages** section of the answer:

> 3. Try to remove the offending package, by force if necessary. You have to be very careful here as you can force the removal of a critical package or, worse, a set of critical packages.
>
>    The following commands go from polite to less polite to outright force. Try them in order.
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg --remove $broken_package
>    sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq $broken_package
>    sudo dpkg --remove --force-all $broken_package
>    ```

I hope that will help somebody. It worked for me.