# How to install all the perl modules in Ubuntu at once

Tags: software-installation, perl, cpan

I want to install LWP::UserAgent. I tried by using metascan manual method. but it has ~50 depedencies.

I was installing RepeatModeler by using the command `perl ./configure`

But I get:

```
The following perl modules required by RepeatModeler are missing from
your system.  Please install these first:
    LWP::UserAgent
```

When I run `sudo apt-get install libwww-perl`

I get

```
[sudo] password for gnomeadmin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-ont-albacore needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Any particular reason why you want to go the manual way? `sudo apt-get install libwww-perl` should be enough.

Comment: My `cpan` is configured to do this. I THINK I told `cpan` to set a config variable, thusly `o conf recommends_policy 1` to set it up.

Comment: @MrShunz Yes, and even when using `cpan LWP::UserAgent` the dependencies of that are fetched automatically.

Comment: You will be able to run the apt command after you fix the problem with `python3-ont-albacore` (is that a custom package). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/967944/how-can-i-reproduce-the-error-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-f

Answer (score 1):

[The comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076322/how-to-install-all-the-perl-modules-in-ubuntu-at-once/1366696#comment1767273_1076322) by [Mr Shunz](https://askubuntu.com/users/4887/mr-shunz) gave a good answer above: The fastest way to install `HTML::Parser`, `LWP::UserAgent`, etc. is just to install the `libwww-perl` package with APT.