# The package linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but an archive for it can't be found

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, software-installation, updates, linux-headers

when I ever I want to make most of the things in terminal I faced this problem ,even when I try to run sudo apt upgrade , it also appear
I try to reinstall it by using
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.4.0-56 linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic
and it appear also

Answer (score 1):

This package was removed from the repositories a few weeks ago. You can resolve the issue by doing this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic
   ```

From here you can clean apt a little bit with:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
```

This should resolve the problem

Comment: when running :sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but an archive for it can't be found.

Comment: then try to remove it with dpkg.  `sudo dpkg -P linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic`

Comment: If that doesn't work, [this is an excellent walk-through of how to remove packages when things go sour](https://askubuntu.com/a/968759/1091774). Scroll down to the "How to manage broken packages" section and start from the first step. Hopefully you don't need to get all the way through to number five.